# Swiftui understanding observedobject in ios 13

Tags: swiftui, observable, observedobject

I have screens in my project where I show the data I have taken from the service.  and in this project there is a custom tabbar and there are three different tabs.  When I press these tabs, I send different requests to the service and update the data.  @stateobject works fine for ios14 and above.  but there is no stateobject in ios13 so I use observedobject.  but I haven't been able to do it completely.  because sometimes data is coming but the ui is not updated or it goes to the previous view.  but when I set a button in the view I want to update and request from here, the data comes up correctly, but when I do it from the tabbar, the errors I mentioned appear.

Comment: The difference between StateObject and ObservedObject is that StateObject has the ability to retain the object. In iOS 13 the very first call (initialization) has to be a State, you cant observe changes from State you can only observe changes in the child when you pass the object to an ObservedObject.

Comment: @loremipsum I'm temporarily solving this situation like this, but that's not what I want.
I don't go to the second screen with a direct navigation link, instead it works when I create a containerview and call the main screen in that view and update the data.
sample code
`
NavigationLink(destination: HotelViewContainer(itemId: place.itemId!, placeName: place.itemName!))

struct HotelViewContainer: View{
     @State var itemId: Int
     @State var placeName: String
     var body: some View{
         HotelView(itemId: itemId, placeName: placeName)
     }
}
`